# "Legally compliant" se traduce "con validez legal"

Tags: traducción

Quisiera confirmar si de verdad la traducción de "legally compliant" en castellano es "[con validez legal](https://www.proz.com/kudoz/english-to-spanish/computers-software/1902000-legally-compliant.html)" en vez de "legalmente conforme". Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Legally compliant" significa "complying with law" (en cumplimiento de la ley/de la normativa).

En el contexto mencionado, "legally compliant digital signature", me parece que "firma digital con validez legal" es una buena traducción. Si algo cumple con la ley, tiene validez legal o es válido desde el punto de vista legal.

En otros contextos, "legally compliant" podrá traducirse como "que cumple(n) la normativa / en cumplimiento de la normativa", por ejemplo:

- legally compliant policies (políticas que cumplen la normativa/en cumplimiento de la normativa)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por sus explicaciones!